# Expression for having one's enthusiasm killed

Tags: expressions

Let's say we have someone who is really energetic and excited about a task they are doing, and then something happens (or someone says something), that totally takes the excitement out of the task away. You could imagine the person "deflating" - for that reason I always thought that "take the steam out" - would be a good expression, but I noticed people sometimes would misunderstand my intention.

Is it a valid expression, or is there something that would fit better in this scenario? I am looking basically how to describe what the event did to the previously energized person.

The country of reference is Canada if that matters.

Comment: Well, someone was a party pooper.

Comment: Yes, I am looking more for how to describe what happened to previously energized person, I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you like nautical terms?

I would say that your poor friend had the [wind knocked out of his sails](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_wind_out_of_someone's_sails#English).

Comment: If you _don't_ like nautical terms there are some nice synonyms on that link too.

Comment: Alternative version is ***take** the wind out of his sails*

Comment: Yeah, that one is the I should have been using. Visually corresponds to deflating pretty well too.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the expression ***[dampen someone's enthusiasm](http://dampen%20someone%E2%80%99s%20enthusiasm%20(=reduce%20it):%20The%20defeat%20did%20not%20dampen%20the%20enthusiasm%20of%20the%20home%20team.)***    to convey the idea of  curbing someone's excitement over something.

> - *dampen someone’s enthusiasm* (=reduce it): The defeat did not dampen the enthusiasm of the home team.

(macmillandictionary.com)

Comment: That's a really good one too.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, **slap in the face**, **sucker punch**, and **put a damper on**.

> **slap in the face**: (figuratively, idiomatic) Something unexpectedly
>   said or done which causes shock or offense; an insult, rebuke, or
>   rebuff. *That Joan's ex-boyfriend turned up to the school dance with
>   Mary was a slap in the face for Joan, and now the girls are no longer
>   best friends*. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slap_in_the_face)
>
> **sucker punch**: a sudden unexpected defeat or setback [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sucker+punch)
>
> **put a damper on**: discourage, dishearten, deter, as in *Grandpa's death
>   put a damper on our Christmas holidays*. This idiom employs the noun
>   damper in the sense of "something that damps or depresses the
>   spirits," a usage dating from the mid-1700s. [The American Heritage®
>   Dictionary of
>   Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+a+damper+on)

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially say **[disillusioned](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disillusioned)** or **[disenchanted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disenchanted)**:

> Alternatively, he has been described by Egyptian officials as a **disillusioned** radical, on his way to meet Hamas in Gaza.
>
> The harshness of everyday reality **disenchanted** him of his idealistic hopes.

Answer (score 0):

verb: **to loose one's motivation**

adjective: **demotivated**

> *from MW* - motivation is the act or process of giving someone a reason
>   for doing something; the condition of being eager to act or work; a
>   force or influence that causes someone to do something.

Example: *Staff may lose motivation in the absence of support and feedback from senior management*.

Answer (score -1):

I would personally consider using the word "thwart" for your situation.